# Dropdown arrow is not displayed in Twitter bootstrap for Firefox browser

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Firefox browser does not display the arrow in a dropdown option.
I can use Twitter bootstrap.

```
<select >
<option>one</option>
<option>two</option>
</select>
```

This is my coding. Chrome browser displayed the arrow but Firefox did not display the arrow .

Here I have attached the sample image. The dropdown arrow is missing in the image

[image]

How can I get FF to display it?

Comment: can you share CSS for select element.

Comment: i does't use any css for this selected element

Answer (score 15):

Actually having the same issue a moment ago.

After removing all of my CSS and anything that could have been causing this, actually found that the Firefox Responsive Design View is the cause.

Comment: Me too. I was stumped. ;)

Comment: Thank you!  I've been trying to fix this for hours!

Comment: Thanks for Sharing

Comment: me for the last hour: arghh, oooooof! WTF!
me now: aaaaahhhhh.

thanks